# Sot convergence of a sequence of operators implies uniform convergence

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, c-star-algebras

Let $H$ be a Hilbert Space. Let $\{A_n\}$ be a sequence of bounded operators in $H$, and $A\in B(H)$.

If $\|A_nf - Af\|\to 0$ uniformly for  $f\in H_{\|.\|=1}\ $, prove that $\|A_n - A\|\to 0$.

Using uniformly boundedness principle, I know $\{A_n-A\}$ is uniformly bounded, but I do not know how to prove convergence. Please help me. Thanks.

EDIT: Is the following argument correct?
For $\epsilon>0$, there is $h\in H$ such that $\|A_n-A\|-\epsilon < \|A_nh-Ah\|$.
 Now when $n\to \infty$, we have desired result.

Comment: Write out what it means to say "$\|A_{n}f-Af\|\rightarrow 0$ uniformly for every $f\in H_{\|\cdot\|=1}$".

Comment: @TrialAndError : The question asks us to prove sot- convergence implies norm convergence.

Comment: You have assumed more than sot convergence. You have assumed uniform sot convergence on the unit disk. That's very different. Again, write out what the condition you stated actually means.

Comment: @TrialAndError : I wrote a simple proof. Please check  it.

Comment: Given $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $N$ such that $\|A_{n}f-Af\| < \epsilon/2$ whenever $n \ge N$ and $\|f\| =1$. Therefore, $\|A_{n}-A\|=\sup_{\|f\|=1} \|A_{n}f-Af\| \le \epsilon/2 < \epsilon$ whenever $n \ge N$.

Comment: @TrialAndError: I do not agree with you. I think the purpose is proving  sot- convergence implies norm convergence

Comment: @TrialAndError: In this case the proof is trivial.

Comment: You have a statement to prove: "If (...), prove ...". The condition (...) is the assumption of uniform convergence on the unit ball. So, the proof is that simple.

Comment: Have you considered the possibility that what you want to prove without the assumption of uniform convergence is false? For example, let $H=L^{2}[0,1]$ and let $A_{n}f = \chi_{[1-1/n,1]}f$. Then $\|A_{n}\|=1$ for all $n$ and $A_{n}f \rightarrow 0$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$ for all $f\in H$. However, what is the norm of $\|A_{n}-0\|$? (By the way, this comes from looking at a spectral measure.)